# Replace radio/checkbox plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugin

I've just created my first plugin, but I think I've written too much bloated code. Could you point me to the right direction?

```
$.fn.replaceme = function() {

    function add_essentials(element) {
        var native_btn = element;
        native_type = native_btn.attr('type');

        native_btn.each(function() {
            var n_btn = $(this);
            n_btn.next('label').addClass('label-replacement');
            n_btn.wrap('<div class="' + native_type + ' input-container"></div>');
            n_btn.parent('.input-container').append('<span class="' + native_type + ' input-replacement"></div>');
        });
    }

    function replace_default_action(element) {
        var input = element;
        group = input.attr('name');

        $('input[name="' + group + '"]').each(function() {

            var input_select = $(this);
            if (input_select.is(':checked')) {
                input_select.siblings('.input-replacement').addClass('selected');
            } else {
                input_select.siblings('.input-replacement').removeClass('selected');
            }
        });
    }

    function label_action(element) {
        element.prevAll('.input-container').children('.styled-input').prop('checked', 'checked').trigger('change');
    }

    function live_check() {
        $('.styled-input:checked').each(function() {
            $(this).siblings('.input-replacement').addClass('selected');
        });
    };

    return this.each(function() {

        var $this = $(this);

        add_essentials($this);
        live_check();

        $('body').on('change', '.styled-input', function() {
            replace_default_action($this);
        });

        $('body').on('click', '.label-replacement', function() {
            label_action($this);
        });
    });
}

$('.styled-input').replaceme();
```

Comment: `group` and `native_type` are globals to start. Edit, also if you'd construct a demo of what your code does on jsfiddle/bin I'd appreciate it

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UCdKL/9/
Here is the fiddle, thanks for your quick response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scanning your code I have a few recommendations to make. If you update your question with a demo I'll make a few more.

As I mentioned in comments you have a few obvious issues with globals

```
var native_btn = element;
native_type = native_btn.attr('type');
//should be
var native_btn = element,
    native_type = native_btn.attr('type');
```

And similarly for `group`. I don't understand why you're doing this

```
function replace_default_action(element) {
        var input = element;
        group = input.attr('name');
```

Why not:

```
function replace_default_action(input) {
    var group = input.attr('name'); //on another note I'd prefer groupName over group
```

Throughout your code you make pretty good use of chaining in places it is clear and concise however there are a few spots I would adapt

Obvious one:

```
$('body').on('change', '.styled-input', function() {
            replace_default_action($this);
        })
        .on('click', '.label-replacement', function() {
            label_action($this);
        });
```

You can write this code with [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) to remove some lines

```
    var input_select = $(this);
    if (input_select.is(':checked')) {
        input_select.siblings('.input-replacement').addClass('selected');
    } else {
        input_select.siblings('.input-replacement').removeClass('selected');
    }

    //With toggle class
    var input_select = $(this);
    input_select.siblings('.input-replacement').toggleClass('selected', input_select.is(':checked'));
```

Also I'm pretty sure you have a logic error here:

```
.append('<span class="' + native_type + ' input-replacement"></div>')
```

Finally in javascript, especially with jQuery code (per [their style guide](http://contribute.jquery.org/style-guide/js/#naming-conventions)), we prefer camelcasing over underscores for names. I'll point you to [this discussion from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789656/why-use-camelcase-in-javascript).

**Update** Here's how I would probably write your code and [here's your updated fiddle up and running](http://jsfiddle.net/UCdKL/10/). As you'll notice I removed all your helper functions that were only called once as there was no need for them and I found them confusing to be honest. I added guiding comments to replace them. I corrected the things mentioned in this review, including function names and condensed ways of writing the original. In the future I think you would benefit from trying to write your functions as straightforward and simple as possible (it took me a while to understand your original code cause of all the helper abstractions)!

```
$.fn.replaceme = function() {
    'use strict';

    return this.each(function() {

        var $this = $(this);
        var native_type = $this.attr('type');

        //setup button for plugin
        $this.each(function() {
            var $btn = $(this);
            $btn.next('label').addClass('label-replacement');
            $btn.wrap('<div class="' + native_type + ' input-container">');
            $btn.parent('.input-container').append('<span class="' + native_type + ' input-replacement">');
        });

        //check if is live
        $('.styled-input:checked').each(function() {
            $(this).siblings('.input-replacement').addClass('selected');
        });

        //handlers
        $('body').on('change', '.styled-input', function() {//set default action, override if already one exists
            var group = $this.attr('name');
            var $cur = $(this);
            $('input[name="' + group + '"]').each(function() {
                $cur.siblings('.input-replacement').toggleClass('selected', $cur.is(':checked'));
            });
        })
        .on('click', '.label-replacement', function() {
            $this.prevAll('.input-container').children('.styled-input').prop('checked', 'checked').trigger('change');
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for reviewing my code, i've learned a few new tips and tricks. Especially about organizing my code. I've got one question, what is the logic error you're pointing out?

Comment: You're opening with a span and closing with a div. Should probably just remove the closing tag `$('<span class="' + native_type + ' input-replacement">')`;

Comment: Wow, it's time to take a nap! Haha, i feel so stupid!

Comment: @JohnElswisk I editted my answer with a counter proposal

Comment: Also looking at it again I'm certain this loop is unnecessary `$('input[name="' + group + '"]').each(function() {`

Comment: Thank you very much, i see what i did 'wrong' now. Today i've written another small plugin for testing purpose with all your comments in mind. And i see that i can write some parts in fewer and more clear code.